# Break MD5 for time verification in URL

Tags: encryption, hash

I'm trying to create a token with expiration time to ensure that the client(in a web application) only has access for a defined amount of time.

I'd like something like https://www.keycdn.com/support/secure-token/

I saw that the aforementioned token is created from a Hash function (MD5), with digest a message with (PATH + SECURETOKEN + TIME), in fact, I guess, that the PATH + SECURETOKEN can be merged in only one variable, say SECURE_CODE.

I suspect that, in the server, when a request is made the URL is parsed, the token is decrypted and the expiration time is verified.

Finally, my question is:

Consider the hash=MD5(SECURETOKEN + TIME), once I have the SECURETOKEN, is it possible to decrypt the hash? If no, how useful is the token for time verification?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: actually I saw this technique twice, in others two different systems. I'd like to understand how this is possible

Comment: Consider using a [hmac](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash-based_message_authentication_code)

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to decrypt the token to verify that it's correct — you just need to recalculate it using the same secret key, and check that the resulting tokens are identical.

In fact, the recommended way to generate (and verify) such tokens would be to use a message authentication code like [HMAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash-based_message_authentication_code) (which uses a hash internally, but does so in a way that's resistant to certain potential attacks). You would provide your secret token key as the key input to HMAC, and data that you want to use the token to verify (i.e.  the path and the expiry time, in this case) as the message. While the *ad hoc* "concatenate and hash" construction used by KeyCDN is probably fine for this particular purpose, it lacks the extensive security analysis and the redundant safety features of HMAC, and *could* be vulnerable to attacks e.g. if the validation code happened to erroneously accept incorrectly formatted expiry timestamps.

Also, in a new system, you really ought to use some other hash function than MD5. While MD5 is still believed to be secure when used in HMAC (or in other applications requiring only irreversibility and not collision resistance), there are known practical attacks that make it completely insecure for some other purposes. A newer and more secure hash function, like SHA-2 or SHA-3, would be a safer choice.

Comment: But how I would do this if the SECRETKEY=SECRETTOKEN+TIME, and the time is get from client time. In server side I have only the SECRETTOKEN and the hash of (SECRETTOKEN+TIME)?

Comment: Look at how the KeyCDN example code you linked to actually calculates the token; e.g. in the PHP example: `$md5 = md5($path.$secret.$expire, true);` (and then `$md5` is base64url encoded to obtain the token). When verifying the token, the server knows `$path` and `$expire` (since they're in the URL) and also `$secret` (since you entered it into the CDN settings), so it can recalculate what the token for that path and expiry time *should* be, if it was generated using the same secret. Note that the secret here is an arbitrary *constant* string; it does *not* depend on the expiry time.

Comment: Ohhhhh! man, this was a silly question... sorry. So without the last paramer, $expire   is not possible to recover part of message, ok?

Comment: No, although of course if you really wanted, you could try a brute force approach, i.e. trying all likely values of `$expire` and seeing which of them (if any) gives the right token.